# Similar library to NullSafe that is not deprecated/unstable

Tags: frameworks, null, ios8

I'm currenty having issues with a library (Nullsafe) that we used for years, and we had to get rid of it because it made tons of crashes.

Getting rid of it made it worse, so, does any of you know a library (or something of the sort) that could replace NullSafe ? (and that would still be okay with iOS8)